# How to dynamically tally result of formula in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet which keeps track of football matches and their scores. Is there a way to tally the results of a formula in the same cell the formula is in?

Column K shows total number of goals scored. I'd like column T to keep track of how many times there were more than 2.5 goals in a match. The formula to check if there are more is no problem, `=IF(K2>2,1,0)` Doing it this way simply gives 0 or 1 all the way down column T. What I am after is as the results are pasted into column K, that corresponding cell in T is tallied, either adding 1 or 0 to the previous cell. So instead of 1s and 0s all the way down, it is counting how many times it was >2. I want this to happen dynamically, so the tally updates as the results are input

Is this possible at all, either using conditional formatting or VBA?

[image]

Comment: Seems possible. Can you show us some sample data then desired output manually? Which version of excel do you have?

Comment: @Harun24HR I added an image above. The total number of goals is in the left hand column and the tally is in the right. Each time there is >2 goals, the tally increases by 1
I hope this helps. cheers

Comment: Yes, understood. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Countifs()` function like-

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,">="&2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much. That tallies the column well. My only question was going to be, how is it possible for it only to tally when there is data in the row? Something along the lines of IF cell in A is blank, do nothing, otherwise perform the COUNTIF function. ```=IF(A2<>"",COUNTIF($K$2:$K2,">="&2.5),"")``` I came up with this from your formula and it seems to work. Thanks so much